# Adding zoom out animation to the activity

Tags: android, animation, android-activity, zooming, out

I have customized my activity to bring it like a dialog. Now I want to stop the default animation and have to add the zoom out animation.

To stop the animation I have tried the following.

```
customDialog.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
```

and in styles

```
  <style name="Theme.CustomDialog" parent="android:style/Theme.Dialog">         
      <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/translucent_background</item>
      <item name="android:activityOpenEnterAnimation">@null</item> 
      <item name="android:activityOpenExitAnimation">@null</item> 
      <item name="android:activityCloseEnterAnimation">@null</item> 
      <item name="android:activityCloseExitAnimation">@null</item> 
      <item name="android:taskOpenEnterAnimation">@null</item> 
      <item name="android:taskOpenExitAnimation">@null</item> 
      <item name="android:taskCloseEnterAnimation">@null</item> 
      <item name="android:taskCloseExitAnimation">@null</item> 
      <item name="android:taskToFrontEnterAnimation">@null</item> 
      <item name="android:taskToFrontExitAnimation">@null</item> 
      <item name="android:taskToBackEnterAnimation">@null</item> 
      <item name="android:taskToBackExitAnimation">@null</item> 
  </style>
```

Even thought it is not working.

Can anyone tel me how to stop the default animation and add the zoom out animation to the activity.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Try this..

```
myIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
```